# uWSGI-tasks spooler cannot import my application

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have a django application with following simplified structure:

```
in_web_server/
├── in_web_server/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── in_web_app/
|    ├── __init__.py
|    └── views/
|        └── ...
└── manage.py
```

Here is `wsgi.py` content:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And here `in_web_server/__init__.py`:

```
from uwsgi_tasks import set_uwsgi_callbacks

set_uwsgi_callbacks()
```

The application is runing within docker container with following `uwsgi.ini` file:

```
[uwsgi]

http = 0.0.0.0:8000
# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir = /app
# Django's wsgi file
module = in_web_server.wsgi:application

static-map = /static=/app/static

# process-related settings
# master
master = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes = 10
# clear environment on exit
vacuum = true

# spooler setup
spooler = /spooler
spooler-processes = 2
spooler-frequency = 10
```

I'm trying to run asynchronous function using the uWSGI spooler. The problem is that when the function is invoked, I get following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uwsgi_tasks/tasks.py", line 70, in manage_spool_request
return task.execute_now()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uwsgi_tasks/tasks.py", line 361, in execute_now
result = super(SpoolerTask, self).execute_now()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uwsgi_tasks/tasks.py", line 218, in execute_now
setattr(self.function, self.attr_name, self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uwsgi_tasks/tasks.py", line 209, in function
self._function = load_function(self.function_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uwsgi_tasks/tasks.py", line 62, in load_function
return import_by_path(func_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uwsgi_tasks/utils.py", line 25, in import_by_path
raise ImportError('Failed to import "{}" - {}'.format(dotted_path, ex))
ImportError: Failed to import "in_web_app.views.api.dashboard.async_function" - No module named 'in_web_app.views'
Spooler message ignored: "{'spooler_task_name': b'uwsgi_spoolfile_on_e76f182f0916_16_1_1531996504_1533579817_175328', b'function_name': b'in_web_app.views.api.dashboard.async_function', b'args': b'\x80\x03).', b'kwargs': b'\x80\x03}q\x00.', b'setup': b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x0b\x00\x00\x00working_dirq\x01X\x04\x00\x00\x00/appq\x02X\x0b\x00\x00\x00retry_countq\x03K\x00u.'}"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uwsgi_tasks/utils.py", line 23, in import_by_path
module = import_module(module_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'in_web_app.views'
```

This exception is gone, when I'll add `from in_web_app.views.api.dashboard import async_function` to the bottom of my `wsgi.py` file. However, this forces me to add every asynchronous function there which is not very convienient solution. What am I doing wrong? Why the spooler cannot import the function if it is not imported from `wsgi.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding root of my project into pythonpath in `uwsgi.ini`. Somehow `.` in the default PYTHONPATH was ignored.

Comment: I don't understand - I've described it above - add root project directory into the `PYTHONPATH`.